Spannig in pst-jtree
I am trying to reproduce the following tree from Merchant (2015). I have no problem with the programming of the tree using John Frampton's pst-jtree package, but the question is whether there is way to reproduce in the tree drawn with pst-jtree the spanning section refering to vocabulary insertion using pstricks code. Thanks in advance.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-jtree}

\begin{document}
    \jtree[scaleby=2 2.5]
     \! = {T}
     :!a {T}({-past, 1sg}) .
    \!a = {Aspect}
    :!b {Aspect}({+perfect}) .
    \!b = {Voice}
    :!c {Voice}({+act}) .
    \!c = {v}
    :{V}(<vert>{$\sqrt{TIE}$}) {v} .
    \endjtree
    
    \end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us your short compilable TeX code you have so far! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Run with lualatex  (creates directly the pdf)  or delete the first line.
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-coil}
\usepackage{pst-jtree}

\begin{document}
\jtree[scaleby=2 2.5]
    \! = {T}
    :!a {T}({\rnode{T}{-past, 1sg}}) .
    \!a = {Aspect}
    :!b {Aspect}({\rnode{perf}{+perfect}}) .
    \!b = {Voice}
    :!c {Voice}({\rnode{act}{+act}}) .
    \!c = {v}
    :{V}(<vert>{\rnode[rb]{TIE}{$\sqrt{TIE}$}}) {\rnode{v}{v}} .
\endjtree
\pnode[0,-10mm](T|TIE){TBottom}%
\pnode[0,-10mm](perf|TIE){perfBottom}%
\pnode[0,-10mm](v|TIE){vBottom}%
\pssin[periods=20,amplitude=0.1,coilarm=0.1](T)(TBottom)
\pssin[periods=15,amplitude=0.1,coilarm=0.1](perf)(perfBottom)
\pssin[periods=10,amplitude=0.1,coilarm=0.1](v)(vBottom)
\pssin[periods=13,amplitude=0.1,coilarm=0.1](act)(vBottom)
\pssin[periods=10,amplitude=0.1,coilarm=0.1](TIE)(vBottom)
\uput[-90](TBottom){o}
\uput[-90](perfBottom){s}
\uput[-90](vBottom){ðe}
    
\end{document}



Thank you very much. I also thought about using pst-coil but I wasn't familiar with it. One small point: is it possible to add some separation between the node and the beginning of the coil with pssin with nodesep or something similar? I tried it, but pssin seems to be inmune to this particular option.

use at least \rnode[b]{foo}{bar}  for all nodes b for bottom instead of the default center
